# Annotations not mapped correctly in plotly heatmap in R shiny

Tags: r, annotations, plotly, heatmap, shinydashboard

I want to plot a dataframe with heatmap in R shiny, with z values annotated.
In python I can do it nicely, but in R I can't, I searched everywhere still haven't figured out how to achieve it.

I created a dataframe as below:

```
index_y <- sort(unique(df2[,"Rank"]))
index_x <- sort(unique(df2[,"Gender"]))

plot_summary <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(index_x)+1, nrow = length(index_y)))
colnames(plot_summary) <- c(as.character(index_x),"Index_y")
plot_summary$Index_y=index_y


for (i in 1:length(index_y)){
  for (j in 1:length(index_x)){

    plot_summary[i,j]=nrow(
      df2[(df2[,"Rank"] %in% index_y[i])&(df2[,"Gender"] %in% index_x[j]),]
    )
  }
}


    > plot_summary
       F      M       Index_x
    1  11258  18753       0
    2  44720  79765       1
    3  35411  43334       2
    4  74847 140577       3
    5  28425  41789       4
    6  34584  50822       5
    7 514662 654434       6
```

And I want to plot it in R shiny dashboard with annotations of the z values.

```
  output$plot21 = renderPlotly(
  plot_ly(data=plot_summary,
          x=index_x,
          y=index_y,
          z=as.matrix(plot_summary[1:length(index_x)]),
          type = "heatmap",colors="YlGnBu") %>%
    add_annotations(x=index_x
                    ,y=index_y
                    ,text=as.matrix(plot_summary[1:length(index_x)])
                    ,showarrow=FALSE
                    ,align="center")%>%
    layout(title="heatmap"
           ,yaxis=list(title=input$attrib22)
           ,xaxis=list(title=input$attrib21)
    )
)
```

But the annotations are not mapped correctly. The z values are right when you mouse over the cell. But the annotated text are jumping from one to another column back and forth somehow...

[image: heatmap]

I think the problem lies in the

```
add_annotation(text=...)
```

But I don't know how to fix them. Please kindly help...

---

Besides, does anyone know how to make the annotation text changing color automatically based on the background color like below?

[image: annocolor]

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: `plot_summary[1:length(index_x)]` is weird because `plot_summary` is two-dimensional.

Comment: Hi Stephane, I put it because I need flexibility to use features other than 'Gender' which may have more than 2 choices...

Comment: getting this too, any updates?